# How can I implement a horizontal page navigation system?

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, edit

The code below is the functionality for a horizontal page dragging navigation system similar to www.blacknegative.com, where the user clicks and drags to the left or right to see the different pages. This is currently set up for four pages, however I need ten pages, and I'm not sure how to update the math included here to add those pages:

```
function initDrag(){
    var selfWidth = $("#proof").width();
    var selfLimit = selfWidth * .75;
    var slide2 = selfWidth * 0.25;
    var slide3 = selfWidth * 0.5;


    var currentIndex = 0;
    var items = [];
    $("#proof > div").each(function(){
        items.push({
            element:$(this),
            id:$(this).attr("id")
        });
    });
    $('#proof').draggable({
        axis: 'x',
        cursor: 'move',
        containment: [-selfLimit, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        start: function(event,ui){
            event.stopPropagation();
            var offsetXPos = parseInt(ui.offset.left) * -1;
            if (offsetXPos >= 0 && offsetXPos < selfWidth * 0.25){
                currentIndex = 0;
            } else if (offsetXPos >= selfWidth * 0.25 && offsetXPos < selfWidth * 0.5){
                currentIndex = 1;
            } else if (offsetXPos >= selfWidth * 0.5 && offsetXPos < selfWidth * 0.75){
                currentIndex = 2;
            } else {
                currentIndex = 3;   
            };
            console.log(currentIndex);
        },
        stop: function(event,ui){
            event.stopPropagation();
            var offsetXPos = parseInt(ui.offset.left) * -1;
            console.log(offsetXPos);
            var updatedPosition;
            if(currentIndex == 0){
                if(offsetXPos >= selfWidth * 0.04){
                    $('#proof').animate({
                        left: slide2 * -1
                    });
                } else {
                    $('#proof').animate({
                        left: 0
                    });
                }
            } else if(currentIndex == 1){
                if(offsetXPos >= selfWidth * 0.29){
                    $('#proof').animate({
                        left: slide3 * -1
                    });
                } else if(offsetXPos <= selfWidth * 0.21){
                    $('#proof').animate({
                        left: 0
                    });
                } else {
                    $('#proof').animate({
                        left: slide2 * -1
                    });
                }
            } else if(currentIndex == 2){
                if(offsetXPos <= selfWidth * 0.46){
                    $('#proof').animate({
                        left: slide2 * -1
                    });
                } else if(offsetXPos >= selfWidth * 0.54){
                    $('#proof').animate({
                        left: selfLimit * -1
                    });
                } else {
                    $('#proof').animate({
                        left: slide3 * -1
                    });
                }
            } else {
                if(offsetXPos <= selfWidth * 0.71){
                    $('#proof').animate({
                        left: slide3 * -1
                    });
                } else {
                    $('#proof').animate({
                        left: selfLimit * -1
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    initDrag();
    window.onresize = function(){
        initDrag();
    };
    $('a.gallery').colorbox();
    //Examples of how to assign the ColorBox event to elements
    $(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1'});
    $(".group2").colorbox({rel:'group2', transition:"fade"});
    $(".group3").colorbox({rel:'group3', transition:"none", width:"75%", height:"75%"});
    $(".group4").colorbox({rel:'group4', slideshow:true});
    $(".ajax").colorbox();
    $(".youtube").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:900, innerHeight:506});
    $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
    $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});
    $(".callbacks").colorbox({
        onOpen:function(){ alert('onOpen: colorbox is about to open'); },
        onLoad:function(){ alert('onLoad: colorbox has started to load the targeted content'); },
        onComplete:function(){ alert('onComplete: colorbox has displayed the loaded content'); },
        onCleanup:function(){ alert('onCleanup: colorbox has begun the close process'); },
        onClosed:function(){ alert('onClosed: colorbox has completely closed'); }
    });

    //Example of preserving a JavaScript event for inline calls.
    $("#click").click(function(){ 
        $('#click').css({"background-color":"#f00", "color":"#fff", "cursor":"inherit"}).text("Open this window again and this message will still be here.");
        return false;
    });



});
```

The CSS to call these pages is #page-1 through #page-4.

Let me know if you need additional information, but my guess and check work has only ruined things.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a simpler yet functional slider system, it doesn't matter whow many div's you have within the proof div

you can view it here [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eT5MM/3/) (Drag to view)

Comment: This is similar to what I'm looking for. Unfortunately, when I try implementing your code into my documents, the functionality doesn't exactly work, and I'm hoping for something where it'll scale based on the size of the browser screen; one where you can't see the screens to the right/left other than when dragging. I'll continue playing around with it, though! Thanks!

Comment: @Pluda here, but on mobile... this will scale to browser since it's width/height 100%. you can place my code within the init function.
I've use #slide_   where you were using #page-  .
Maybe you want to make one jsfiddle so I can see ( tomorrow ) what is happening?

Comment: Thanks, I will try that and report back!

Comment: here is what happens when I've tried: http://jsfiddle.net/zvrGc/  I'm not terribly familiar with JS or Jquery (can make minor edits, and what not), so please let me know if you notice I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Update: I've got it to work, however it only scrolls to the right, and  won't scroll back through the previous pages.

Comment: Hello, now I'm leaving office, can we see that tomorrow? You're using mootools wich I don't, I was using jquery 1.7.2.  But I think you need to choose to use my code your the previous one, not both at same time, because it will be messy.

Comment: Hi Pluda, I've changed the code to download whatn you've posted on jsfiddle.net only, and that's where it loops through the screens with only functionality to scroll/drag to the right, not to the left. I would need it to scroll to the left and right. Thanks!

Comment: ok, it is ok like I did, but you need it scroling/dragging in both directions. Got it, tomorrow I will try to fix it, ok?

Comment: you're welcome, you should now accept the answer  so other users now this question was solved

Comment: Hi Pluda, One additional quick question: Whenever I resize the page when I'm on one of the scrolled pages, the content completely disappears. Do you know why this is?

Comment: Yes, I've noticed that, I know what is wrong, but I don't see how to fix it... the problem is that we need to know 1st wich slide is onScreen and then when window resize finishes recalculate the positions of elements.  You should start a new question with this problem, maybe someone will help us now